Is there oriented scalar field line integral, or non-oriented vector field line integral?
I'm studying complex (integral) analysis and struggling with it. BTW, this is my first math stackexchange question, so please forgive any mistakes on my part.
We have definition of complex line inetegral:
Def. Line Integral for complex function

For simplicity, all definitions will be given in terms of parametrizations rather than path images or equivalence classes.

For generallity, i won't assume smooth structure. That is, These definitions involve retifiable path, Stieltzes integral, etc..

Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ be retifiable path, and let $f:\gamma([a,b])\to\mathbb{C}$ be continuous.

A line integral of f along $\gamma$ is defined by $\int_\gamma f(z)dz:=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))d\gamma(t)$.

Let $s:[a,b]\to[0,L(\gamma)], s(t)=L(\gamma|_{[a,t]}$). This is continuous and increasing, and hence bounded variation.

(What's this called?) $\int_\gamma f(z)|dz|:=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))ds(t)$.


So far, so good. The problem is that I learned calculus. I found these definition of real line integral:
Def. Line Integral for real function (Smooth Version)

Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be piecewise smooth path, and let $f:U(\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n)\to\mathbb{R}$, $F:U(\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous where $U$ is open and $\gamma([a,b])\subseteq U$

A line integral of f along $\gamma$ is defined by $\int_\gamma f(x)ds:=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)|dt$.

A line integral of F along $\gamma$ is defined by $\int_\gamma F(x)\cdot d\gamma:=\int_a^bF(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)dt$.


I wasn't satisfied with this definition, because it requires smooth structure. Hence, this is (i think) my refinement of the definition.
Def. Line Integral for real function (More General Version)

Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be rectifiable path, and let $f:\gamma([a,b])\to\mathbb{R}$, $F:\gamma([a,b])\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous.

A line integral of f along $\gamma$ is defined by $\int_\gamma f(x)ds:=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))ds(t)$.

Let $\gamma^i, F^i$ be $i$-th components of $\gamma, F$, respectively. Then $\gamma^i$ is rectifiable, and $F^i$ is continuous.

A line integral of F along $\gamma$ is defined by $\int_\gamma F(x)\cdot d\gamma=\int_a^bF(\gamma(t))\cdot d \gamma(t):=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_a^b{F^i(\gamma(t))d \gamma^i(t)}$.


But after refined, I became confused. My question is: A (real) vector field line integral corresponds a complex line integral (at least we corresponds dot product $\cdot$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and complex multiplication $\times$ on $\mathbb{C}$ like in differentiation), but why (real) scalar field line integral seems to be corresponds $\int_\gamma f(z)|dz|$? Why don't we define $\int_\gamma fdx$, $\int_\gamma f|dx|$=$\int_\gamma fds$ and $\int_\gamma F\cdot dx$, $\int_\gamma F|dx|$=$\int_\gamma Fds$ like in complex case? Why vector case have orientation but not scalar case?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
